# Оборот речи

Tags: словосочетание

Добрый день!
Есть ли такой оборот речи "одновременно прилагаю" и как его лучше использоваь?

Answer (score 1):

Оборота такого не знаю, это случайное образование, например, вот  с сайтов:"Можно ли к ПРЕТЕНЗИИ ОДНОВРЕМЕННО ПРИЛАГАТЬ ЗАЯВЛЕНИЕ О ВОЗБУЖДЕНИИ ПРИКАЗНОГО ПРОИЗВОДСТВА?".

"Силясь понять сказку, он одновременно прилагает усилия и к тому, чтобы понять слова, из которых она состоит, проводить между ними аналогии, делать выводы, расширять или сужать, уточнять или..."

Осуществляя первые социалистические мероприятия, Советская власть одновременно прилагала все усилия для освобождения Лори от оккупировавших его войск меньшевистской Грузии.

По этой причине местные власти в Китае, России и других подобных странах с утроенной энергией ополчились на интеллектуальных пиратов, одновременно прилагая усилия по созданию своих собственных..